# Get String From Another Method?

Tags: java, string, oop, methods

I have two methods, the first one creates a string, then I want to use that string in the second method.

When I researched this, I came across the option of creating the string outside of the methods, however, this will not work in my case as the first method changes the string in a couple of ways and I need the final product in the second method.

Code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class yaya {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a word:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        Random ran = new Random();
        int ranNum = ran.nextInt(10);
        input = input + ranNum;
    }

    public void change(String[] args) {
        //more string things here
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know what the keyword _return_ does?

Comment: are both methods called independently, or is the one method called from the other?

Comment: Show us the code in question.

Comment: You may want to add some code to explain your question, so that the question is answerable without guessing your intentions.

Comment: Both methods are called independently, and no, I don't know what return does.

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer, declare the `String input` outside `main` function as a class variable. This will solve your problem.

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta Your answer does not seem appropriate and - particularly for a beginner - suggesting the use of the `static` keyword without providing any details on the implications and limitations of this is quite dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an instance variable:

```
public class MyClass {

    private String str;

    public void method1() {
        // change str by assigning a new value to it
    }

    public void method2() {
        // the changed value of str is available here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to *return* the modified string from the first method and pass it into the second. Suppose the first method replaces all instances or 'r' with 't' in the string (for example):

```
public class Program
{
    public static String FirstMethod(String input)
    {
        String newString = input.replace('r', 't');
        return newString;
    }

    public static String SecondMethod(String input)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String test = "Replace some characters!";
        test = FirstMethod(test);
        test = SecondMethod(test);
    }
}
```

Here, we pass the string into the first method, which gives us back (*returns*) the modified string. We update the value of the initial string with this new value and then pass that into the second method.

If the string is strongly tied to the object in question and needs to be passed around and updated a lot within the context of a given object, it makes more sense to make it an instance variable as Bohemian describes.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the modified string in the second method as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

create a static variable used the same variable in both the method.

Comment: why static? this seems not needed

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass {

  public string method1(String inputStr) {
    inputStr += " AND I am sooo cool";

    return inputStr;
  }

  public void method2(String inputStr) {
    System.out.println(inputStr);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String firstStr = "I love return";

    String manipulatedStr = method1(firstStr);

    method2(manipulatedStr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that both methods should be able to be called independently, you should try something like this:

```
public class Strings {

public static String firstMethod() {
    String myString = ""; //Manipulate the string however you want
    return myString;
}

public static String secondMethod() {
    String myStringWhichImGettingFromMyFirstMethod = firstMethod();
    //Run whatever operations you want here and afterwards... 
    return myStringWhichImGettingFromMyFirstMethod;
}
}
```

Because both of these methods are static, you can call them in main() by their names without creating an object. Btw, can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?